# Passing data from non-activity class to an activity class using bundle

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I want to pass a variable from my broadcastreceiver class which has an activity to another activity but the app always crashes. Need help on this. Here's my code

Broadcastreceiver:

```
Bundle dataBundle = new Bundle();
dataBundle.putString("date", dateFormat);
Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, MapsActivity.class);

intent1.putExtras(dataBundle);
```

Activity class:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String container = extras.getString("date");

date = container;
```

Comment: CatLog error ?!

Comment: I forgot the catlog error, but the app always crash. Are my codes correct?